# How do I alter the properties of ng-model of angular bootstrap-ui radio button?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

My HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="btn-group">
        <label class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="radioModel" uib-btn-radio="'Topics'" ng-click="buttonClick('Topics');">Topics</label>
        <label class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="radioModel" uib-btn-radio="'People'" ng-click="buttonClick('Person');">People</label>
        <label class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="radioModel" uib-btn-radio="'Companies'" ng-click="buttonClick('Company');">Companies</label>
        <label class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="radioModel" uib-btn-radio="'Organizations'" ng-click="buttonClick('Organization');">Organizations</label>
</div>
```

I am trying to print the values of these buttons when I click them. Under the `ng-click` function, I put the following statement :

```
console.log($scope.radioModel);
```

But console says `undefined`.
buttonClick is shown below:

```
$scope.buttonClick = function (index) {
    if (index == "Topics") {
        $scope.update_cloud_keywords();
        console.log($scope.radioModel);

    }
    else if (index == "Person") {
        $scope.update_cloud_entities("Person");
        console.log($scope.radioModel);
    }
    else if (index == "Company") {
        $scope.update_cloud_entities("Company");
        console.log($scope.radioModel);
    }
    else if (index == "Organization") {
        $scope.update_cloud_entities("Organization");
        console.log($scope.radioModel);
    }
    else
        console.log("error");
};
```

How can I read and alter the values of the bootstrap-ui button ?

Reference to documentation : 
https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Comment: Could you add all of the `buttonClick()` function ?

Comment: @Korte added :)

Comment: Does the `$scope.radioModel` get involved in `$scope.update_cloud_entities` ?

Comment: @Korte No. There is no $scope.radioModel in the entire method.

Comment: Could you recreate the problem in a plunker ?

Answer (score 0):

If you use angularjs, you need to use `$log` instead of standart `console.log`.

For example: `$log.debug($scope.radioModel);`.

And don't forget to inject `$log` service in your controller!

Comment: Why it's so necessary to use $log service? I guess it is not a solution.